# ViewportSizing maximumViewportInset cannot be larger than frame

Tags: uikit, wkwebview

I create my WebView (WKWebView) programmatically and get this error in Xcode console when loading an HTML string. The WebView, at the moment of loading, is not a part of the view hierarchy.

```
[ViewportSizing] maximumViewportInset cannot be larger than frame
```

Relates to Xcode 15.1 beta 3, iOS 17.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the frame, which is currently set to zero when created programmatically with the default initializer. The solution is to set the frame to a non-zero value. This can be done manually or by using UIKit AutoLayout when the WebView is added to the view hierarchy.